# Can a creature who is exhausted benefit from bonuses to speed?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, conditions

In D&D 5th Edition, there is a status effect called [Exhaustion](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Conditions#toc_16), which is measured in six levels. Level 5 Exhaustion reduces the speed of a creature to 0.

> $$
> \begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline
> \textbf{Level} & \textbf{Effect} \\
> \hline
> \text{1} & \text{Disadvantage on ability checks} \\
> \hline
> \text{2} & \text{Speed halved} \\
> \hline
> \text{3} & \text{Disadvantage on attack rolls and saving throws} \\
> \hline
> \text{4} & \text{Hit point maximum halved} \\
> \hline
> \text{5} & \text{Speed reduced to 0} \\
> \hline
> \text{6} & \text{Death} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

> *- PHB 291*

There are two other conditions that have a similar effect to this, [Grappled](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Conditions#toc_6) and [Restrained](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Conditions#toc_13).

> A grappled creature's speed becomes 0, and it can't benefit from any bonus to its speed. - (PHB, p. 290)

> A restrained creature's speed becomes 0, and it can't benefit from any bonus to its speed. - (PHBl, p. 292)

In addition, there are spells such as *Longstrider*, which increase movement speed by a fixed amount (10 feet for *Longstrider*).

Are bonuses to speed negated by having level 5 exhaustion or can that creature freely move when under an effect that increases its speed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## An exhausted creature can benefit from a bonus to its speed.

A condition does only what it says. The *grappled* and *restrained* conditions, as you cited them, state explicitly that the creature can't benefit from any bonus to its speed, but the *exhaustion* condition states no such thing, nor is there a general rule prohibiting the benefit of bonuses to speed when a creature's speed is reduced to 0.

Specific beats general, so a spell like *longstrider* would supersede the more general exhaustion condition (on the assumption that one spell out of hundreds is more specific than one common condition out of about a dozen). Otherwise, if that were not the intended precedence, then the *grappled* and *restrained* conditions would not even need to state the exception.

This is upheld by Jeremy Crawford, lead rules designer for 5e: "Having 5 levels of exhaustion reduces your speed to 0, but it doesn't prevent bonuses to speed from applying to you." ([Source](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/940660867577692160))

This is not surprising if you consider each condition thematically: *grappled* and *restrained* represent external factors locking a creature in place to restrict their ability to move (and gaining a bonus to speed would not circumvent that restriction), whereas *exhaustion* represents the creature's fatigue robbing them of the energy or gumption to move (but gaining a bonus to speed, likely via magic, could overcome that by effectively energizing or motivating them).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75065/discussion-on-answer-by-bloodcinder-can-a-creature-who-is-exhausted-benefit-from).

Comment: I'm not sure fatigue actually robs you of gumption.  More like moxie.